# Angular 5- Where should logout code sit?

Tags: angularjs, angular2

I want to create Logout Functionality in Angular 5. The logout function will contain following pseudo code:

1. Clear local storage authentication JWT token
2. Redirect to login page

My question is; where should the above code be; In a component or in a service?

I believe, a service should contain logic which interacts with backend only and component should contain presentation logic (Correct me if I am wrong).

As the logout code isn't any logic dealing with backend, it should ideally sit in a component. But, if I have to perform the same operation of the logout somewhere else, it will be easier to call the service and execute the code rather than writing the same two lines again in some different component.

So where should the code really be?

Comment: If you don't interact with the backend then you're not really logging out, as a stolen JWT can continue to be used until it hits expiry.

Comment: I don't store the token anywhere in the backend. How will I invalidate it on logout?
And I plan to use HTTPS. SO how can the token be stolen?

Comment: You would create a collection of logged-out / revoked tokens that ejects the tokens when they expire (so it only takes the resources it needs).  Presumably this is small enough that you can cache it on the server(s) and not worry about a DB roundtrip unless you want to.  In transit isn't the only way to steal tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is pretty explicit about that:
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

> A component should not need to define things like how to fetch data
>   from the server, validate user input, or log directly to the console.
>   Instead, it can delegate such tasks to services. By defining that kind
>   of processing task in an injectable service class, you make it
>   available to any component. You can also make your app more adaptable
>   by injecting different providers of the same kind of service, as
>   appropriate in different circumstances.

According to that, it is fine, even encouraged to encapsulate your non-networking related logic into services too.

So, yes, you should put your logout logic into a service and call it from the components.